# Maintain Scroll Position on farm library page

Tags: client-side-rendering

Let's say I have a form library list with 30 items.

If a user click the 30th item and open and close the form, then the scroll position should be same as when the user clicked the list item (30th item).

In my form library page, the scroll is going back to top and it's not maintaining the exact position where the user clicked the list item. I am using SharePoint 2013.

`maintainscrollpositiononpostback` methods has been tried but to no use. Need Javascript